# Google Timeline: is it encrypted and if so who has the key?

Tags: encryption, privacy

Google Timeline claims (e.g. [here](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6258979?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)) that "Your Timeline is private, so only you can see it."

What does that mean? As a cryptographer I would take that to mean that the Timeline data is encrypted using a key that only I have access to.

But based on some of the features, that doesn't seem likely. For instance it can be accessed from any device provided I log in to my Google account, which would make key management hard. It seems that the recommendations it sends are based on it doing some ML on the data, which would be very hard to do if it were encrypted. And it now [sends an email](https://9to5google.com/2020/01/09/google-maps-2019-timeline/) with a customized summary of annual activity. (I don't actually have Timeline enabled; this information is based on what I've heard from friends and seen online.)

Is Google actually doing some fancy FHE or MPC thing to analyze Timeline data while it's encrypted? Is the data being processed by your local devices? Or by "only you" does Google mean "only you and Google"?

(Note: I originally asked this question at [crypto.stackexchange.com](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/78022) and was advised to move it here. It may also be possible that only Google knows the answer to this question.)

Comment: You are interpreting their comments through your context of what you hope they mean, then asking a question based on the assumption that your interpretation is accurate and precise. "Private" can mean a very wide range of things.

Comment: I'm closing because we cannot comment on the internal processes of a company. This is a question for them. However, there is no evidence to suggest that any encryption is being done at all, so the question becomes an X/Y problem.

Answer (score 1):

It means they will not post it in public places, not show it on other people devices, things like that. It's like those sites who ask your email and say it will be kept private, unlike your picture and nickname that are public. It's not private on the crypto sense, more on layman's sense...

It does not mean it's encrypted in any way or form, or only you can see it (and they cannot). It's a way more relaxed definition of *private*.

Comment: Is this your extraction from Google's limited information or you have got some other source?